# CakePHP 2.0.4 - findBy magic methods with conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements, cakephp-2.0, magic-methods, findby

I am trying to build a small cms to test CakePHP 2.x

In my PagesController (for displaying single sites), I use this code:

```
$page = $this->Page->findByNavtitle($name, array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Page.visible' => '1',
        ),
    )
);
```

The result should only set when the record is marked as visible.
But this codeblock throws an error.

The API describes, that just one parameter is allowed in these findBy magic methods.

How can I get the result with conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add conditions to **findBy** method. Instead use **find**:

```
$page = $this->Page->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Page.nav_title'     => $name,
    'Page.visible' => 1
  )
));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll use **find** instead.

Answer (score 0):

$this->Model->findAllBy(string $value, array $fields, array $order, int $limit, int $page, int $recursive);

Answer (score 0):

Findbyid in cake php

```
$result = $this->Modelname->findById($id, array('Alpha.name'));
```

where $id is an id of record you're searching for and Alpha.name is a field you need (e.g. name from model Alpha)