# CakePHP magic findBy method for comparisons

Tags: cakephp, php, magic-methods, cakephp-2.2

We have plots and beans that can be planted into the plots.

I am absolutely determined to use the following to find all plots the owner has, with a bean inside them.

$plots = $this->Plot->findAllByOwnerAndBean_id(uid, '> 0');

However, it gives me the SQL `WHERE`Plot`.`owner`= '15' AND`Plot`.`bean_id`= '> 0'`

[This suggests it may be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725495/cakephp-2-0-4-findby-magic-methods-with-conditions), but I don't feel it's definitive. (potentially, even relevant as 2.2?) And it may be, so the question is two-fold:

How do I get what I want out of the findBy, and if I really can't, how could I avoid less code than the following, which I can confirm works?

```
$plots = $this->Plot->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
        'owner'     => uid,
        'bean_id >' => 0
      )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how it would be possible with magic methods (may work with DboSource::expression() but if its user input you'd have to sanitize it yourself). You can, however, just make a helper method in your model.

```
class Plot extends AppModel {

    public function findAllByOwnerAndBeanId($owner, $beanId) {
        return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'owner'     => $owner,
                'bean_id >' => $beanId,
             ),
        ));
    }

}
```

Edit: You may instead try the following, but note that it's not tested.

```
$ds = $this->Plot->getDataSource();
$plots = $this->Plot->findAllByOwnerAndBean_id($uid, $ds->expression('> ' . intval($userInputtedBeanId)));
```

May be better for `Sanitize::escape()` rather than intval.

Comment: Sadly it seems there really is no way to do what I want. $ds-> didn't work, but thanks for the effort. As for defining the function, it eliminates my need for this. :P I'll push on with the find() and see if anyone has anything else to say. Thanks so much.

Comment: Doesn't totally eliminate the need. It makes your code more re-usable and testable. Fatter models, skinnier controllers.